# Como resolver TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: react

Estou recebendo o erro TypeError: Cannot read property 'nextPage' of undefined quando tento utilizar o valor já setado da página para receber um novo resultado paginado. No caso eu consigo ler o valor da primeira vez, porém ao retornar para realizar uma nova requisição o valor do state não é reconhecido.

Estou tentando utilizar o InfiniteScroll no react para receber novos resultados com paginação sempre que descer ao fim da página.

Aqui está o meu InfiniteScroll, onde os valores estão vindo certos:

```
companyMarketplaces() {
        console.log("AQUI RESULTADOS: ");
        console.log("MARKETPLACES: ");
        console.log(this.state.companyMarketplaces);
        console.log("PAGINA: ");
        console.log(this.state.nextPage);
        if(this.state.companyMarketplaces.totalElements > 0) {
            return (
                <div>
                     <InfiniteScroll
                        dataLength={this.state.companyMarketplaces.totalElements}
                        next={this.companyMarketplacesList}
                        hasMore={this.state.hasMore}
                        loader={<h4>Carregando...</h4>}
                    >
                    {this.state.companyMarketplaces.content.map((marketplace) => {
                        return <ImageCard
                            avatar={Logo}
                            content={
                            <h3>{marketplace.name}</h3>
                            }   
                            options={
                            <Button color="danger" onClick={this.toggle}>
                                CONECTAR
                            </Button>
                            }
                            width={this.state.width}
                        />
                    })}
                    </InfiniteScroll>
                </div>
            );
        } else {
            return <Alert color="info">Não existem marketplaces vinculados!</Alert>
        }
    }
```

E aqui, ao chegar no final da página e buscar novos resultados, o erro ocorre, não encontrando o estado nextPage:

```
companyMarketplacesList() {
        console.log(this.state.nextPage);
        this.CompanyService.readMarketplaces(this.props.profile.id, this.state.nextPage,
            (result) => {
                if(this.state.companyMarketplaces.totalElements > 0) {
                    let newArray = this.state.companyMarketplaces;
                    newArray.numberOfElements = newArray.numberOfElements + result.numberOfElements;
                    newArray.content.concat(result.content);
                    this.setState({companyMarketplaces: newArray});
                } else {
                    this.setState({companyMarketplaces: result});
                }
                if(result.totalPages-1>this.state.nextPage) {
                    this.setState({nextPage: this.state.nextPage+1, hasMore: true});
                }
            },
            (erro) => {
                console.log("Erro:");
                console.log(erro);
            }
        );
    }
```

Classe completa:

```
class Marketplaces extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      width: Screen.getWidth(),
      linkMarketplaceID: "",
      availableMarketplaces: [],
      companyMarketplaces: {},
      modal: false, 
      hasMore: false,
      nextPage: 0
    };
    this.MarketplaceService = new MarketplaceService();
    this.CompanyService = new CompanyService();
    this.availableMarketplacesList();
    this.companyMarketplacesList();
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
    Screen.updateDimensions();
    window.addEventListener("resize", Screen.updateDimensions.bind(this));
}

availableMarketplacesList() {
    this.MarketplaceService.read(this.props.profile.id,
        (result) => {
            console.log(result);
            this.setState({availableMarketplaces: result});
            if(result.length > 0)
                this.setState({linkMarketplaceID: result[0].id});
        },
        (erro) => {
            console.log("Erro:");
            console.log(erro);
        }
    );
}

toggle() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      modal: !prevState.modal
    }));
  }

companyMarketplacesList() {
    console.log(this.state.nextPage);
    this.CompanyService.readMarketplaces(this.props.profile.id, this.state.nextPage,
        (result) => {
            if(this.state.companyMarketplaces.totalElements > 0) {
                let newArray = this.state.companyMarketplaces;
                newArray.numberOfElements = newArray.numberOfElements + result.numberOfElements;
                newArray.content.concat(result.content);
                this.setState({companyMarketplaces: newArray});
            } else {
                this.setState({companyMarketplaces: result});
            }
            if(result.totalPages-1>this.state.nextPage) {
                this.setState({nextPage: this.state.nextPage+1, hasMore: false});
            }
        },
        (erro) => {
            console.log("Erro:");
            console.log(erro);
        }
    );
}

linkMarketplace() {
    this.CompanyService.linkMarketplace(this.props.profile.id, this.state.linkMarketplaceID,
        (success) => {
            console.log(success);
            this.availableMarketplacesList();
            this.setState({companyMarketplaces: {}, nextPage: 0, hasMore: false});
            this.companyMarketplacesList();
        },(error) => {
            console.log("Erro!");
            console.log(error);
        }
    )
}

setValues(attribute, value) {
    this.setState(
        (estado) => estado[attribute] = value
    );
}

availableMarketplaces() {
    if(this.state.availableMarketplaces.length > 0) {
        return (
            <div>
                <Row>
                    <Col md={12}>
                        <FormGroup>
                            <Label for="linkMarketplace">Vincular Marketplace</Label>           
                            <Input type="select" name="select" id="linkMarketplace" onChange={(e) => {this.setValues("linkMarketplaceID", e.target.value)}}>
                                {this.state.availableMarketplaces.map((marketplace) => {
                                    return <option value={marketplace.id}>{marketplace.name}</option>
                                })}
                            </Input>                      
                        </FormGroup>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Col md={3}>
                        <CustomButton fill color="success" onClick={() => {this.linkMarketplace()}}>Vincular</CustomButton>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <br/>
            </div>
        );
    } else return "";
}

companyMarketplaces() {
    console.log("AQUI RESULTADOS: ");
    console.log("MARKETPLACES: ");
    console.log(this.state.companyMarketplaces);
    console.log("PAGINA: ");
    console.log(this.state.nextPage);
    if(this.state.companyMarketplaces.totalElements > 0) {
        return (
            <div>
                 <InfiniteScroll
                    dataLength={this.state.companyMarketplaces.totalElements}
                    next={this.companyMarketplacesList}
                    hasMore={this.state.hasMore}
                    loader={<h4>Carregando...</h4>}
                >
                {this.state.companyMarketplaces.content.map((marketplace) => {
                    return <ImageCard
                        avatar={Logo}
                        content={
                        <h3>{marketplace.name}</h3>
                        }   
                        options={
                        <Button color="danger" onClick={this.toggle}>
                            CONECTAR
                        </Button>
                        }
                        width={this.state.width}
                    />
                })}
                </InfiniteScroll>
            </div>
        );
    } else {
        return <Alert color="info">Não existem marketplaces vinculados!</Alert>
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="content">
            <Container fluid>
                {this.availableMarketplaces()}
                <Row>
                    <Col md={12}>
                        {this.companyMarketplaces()}
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <div>
                    <Modal isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle={this.toggle}>
                    <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}>Login</ModalHeader>
                    <ModalBody>
                        <Iframe url="https://www.mercadolivre.com/jms/mlb/lgz/login?platform_id=ml&go=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mercadolivre.com.br%2F&loginType=explicit#nav-header"
                            width="100%"
                            id="marketplaceLogin"
                            height="100%"
                            frameBorder="0"
                        />
                    </ModalBody>
                    <ModalFooter>
                        <Button color="secondary" onClick={this.toggle}>Cancel</Button>
                    </ModalFooter>
                    </Modal>
                </div>
            </Container>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

export default Marketplaces;

Comment: Em qual linha ocorre o erro?

Comment: Ocorre na primeira linha do companyMarketplacesList(), onde eu tento imprimir o valor no console.

Comment: Ele seta o valor da página na primeira vez, mas na segunda, depois de descer toda a página, ele não reconhece mais o estado.

Comment: A função `companyMarketplacesList` está dentro de uma classe certo? Pode colocar toda classe?

Comment: Claro! Editei a postagem com a classe completa.

Comment: Tente trocar `this.companyMarketplacesList();` por `this.companyMarketplacesList.call(this);` na função `linkMarketplace`

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou. O erro ainda ocorre.